# Making a web page from many php/html pages

Tags: php, html, web

I have a web page which made up of three pages[Header, Content, Footer]. I have something like as follows in my code

```
<?php
 if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE){
    session_start();
 }

 if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    include('header.php');
    include('body.php');
    include('footer.html');
 }else {
    header('Location: users.php');
 }
?>
```

Is there anything wrong with this approach? Are I am doing the right thing? I am not facing any problems since I am a newbie So I am not much aware of the issues. I just want to know good/bad practice to achive this?

I have this kind of set up because header & footer is common for all my pages. So I just modify the centre portion.

Comment: Depends on the purpose of the website. What category does this site come under?

Comment: I'd add an `exit()` after the redirect. Besides, the code looks fine though.

Comment: @GopsAB Code is fine, approach is fine, question is somewhat unclear :-)

Comment: @Jan Thanks. I just started writing sites by referring documentation. I am unaware of good/bad practices. I just wanted to know whether my apporach is the best one. Or there any problems with that.

Comment: This is a fine approach to start out with - when new at PHP. Eventually you can make this solution a bit more complex and dynamically load the body based on a URL parameter. But there is nothing wrong with this approach in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

For what you're trying to achieve, this approach is perfectly fine.

Although as your files and directories will increase in number, sometimes it'll get frustrating to remember the location of those files and using include accordingly. i.e. `include("../../static_pages/body.php")`.

So you should put `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` at the beginning and use it accordingly to use the same URLs in whole websites.

i.e. `include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."static_pages/body.php")`

Oh, mind the difference between `require` and `include`. `require` will stop execution when file is not found whereas `include` will just throw a warning.

Both have their importance. :D

Comment: Thanks for your informations.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's nothing wrong with your approach. However, I am not a professional or something but if it works it should be alright because I think it is a secure way of displaying your page.

Comment: This is rather a comment.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I am still kinda new and still getting used to how everything works around here.